# Hyper-V server with multiple subnets and Active Directory Policies and adding domain objects to local groups not working

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, rras

My lab is a test HP computer connected to a port on my wireless router. It is running Windows 2012 R2 with the Hyper-V role and I am trying to simulate multiple testing subnets to test a number of scenarios. Everything appears to be working correctly with basic IP connectivity between the subnets and out to the internet. However, machines in the 3rd network aren't getting AD policies from my DC in the 2nd network. Has anyone seen this before? Is there something I have overlooked?

Thanks,
Chris

1 Cisco Wireless Router (to internet)
    IP Address: 192.168.1.1
    DHCP Pool: 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.100

1 HP computer
    Running Windows Server 2012 R2 with Hyper-V role installed
    RRAS role installed and configured
    IP Address of Management OS: 192.168.1.200 (static)

```
Hyper-V Manager Virtual Switch Info:
------------------------------------
Virtual Switch 1 (External): vNET 1 (192.168.1.0/24)    
Virtual Switch 2 (Internal): vNET 2 (192.168.2.0/24)
Virtual Switch 3 (Internal): vNET 3 (192.168.3.0/24)

Network Connections Window:
---------------------------
External NIC - Enabled
Virtual NIC 1: vNET1 - 192.168.1.200 - Network - Internet access
Virtual NIC 2: vNET2 - 192.168.2.1 - LAB_DOMAIN - Internet access
Virtual NIC 3: vNET3 - 192.168.3.1 - LAB_DOMAIN - No Internet access (this is working!?)

RRAS configuration:
-------------------
NAT enabled - on vNET1 NIC
LAN Routing enabled
```

## WORKING:

```
HOST
    Ping
    SMB
    AD functionality
    Internet connectivity
All VMs on vNET2 network
    (Lab VM machine with AD & DNS)
    (10+ machines running Server and Workstation OSes)
    Ping
    SMB
    AD functionality
    Internet connectivity
All VMs on vNET3 network
    (3+ machines)
    Ping
    SMB
    Internet connectivity
```

## NOT WORKING:

```
All VMs on vNET3
    AD functionality
       - Active Directory Policy not coming down
        EventID 1129 "The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of
        network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient
        condition. A success message would be generated oncwe the machine
        gets connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has 
        successfully processed." 
       - Unable to add domain groups, users or computers to local groups 
                  (however, it does resolve the names when you click on 'Check Names')
        ERROR MSG:
          Window Title: Local Users and Groups
          Body: Information returned from the object picker for  
                            object "<group/user/computer>" was incomplete. The object will 
                            not be processed.
```

Several attempts to troubleshoot the issue by disabling the firewall on a VM in vNET3 or running gpudate crashes the Hyper-V server. I have now done this 4 times in less than 4 hours.

Comment: Can you in fact ping from any subnet to any other subnet?

Comment: Are you running RRaS on the Hyper-V host?

Comment: Yes, I can ping all subnets from all other subnets as mentioned above. Yes, I am running RRAS on the Hyper-V host.

Comment: Full stop. Get RRAS and anything but Hyper-V off of the base installation. If you want routing of some kind do it in a VM, not the host.

Comment: This is for a lab environment, not production, and I followed a test build out on TechNet "Configuring Hyper-V for multiple subnets with only one NIC (Server 2012 R2 Edition)" to do this. Since none of the comments left there referred to any issues like this, I was wondering if anyone on this forum had seen this. The BSODs I am seeing indicate that there is a kernel mode bug I am hitting that may or may not be linked to RRAS on the Hyper-V host. Trying to keep the test lab simple using Hyper-V Manager and not having to roll out VMM for advanced networking.